# RxJava Single<> with count, Predicate and delay

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm doing retrofit network calls, which all use a Single<> returnable. On any error, I do a retry based on a predicate, upto 3 times. But I'd like to introduce a delay or exponential backoff. How do I add this delay?

```
public <T> SingleTransformer<T, T> applySchIoAndRetry() {

    return new SingleTransformer<T, T>() {
        @Override
        public SingleSource<T> apply(Single<T> upstream) {
            return upstream
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .retry(3, new Predicate<Throwable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean test(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {

                            if (throwable instanceof HttpException) {
                                HttpException exception = (HttpException) throwable;
                                return (exception.code() != 400);
                            }

                            return false;
                        }
                    });
        }
    };
}
```

And I call it here:

```
public Single<Foo> bar() {
    return apiService.foobar()
            .compose(rxHelper.applySchIoAndRetry());
}
```

Comment: Use `retryWhen`; [its Javadoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#retryWhen-io.reactivex.functions.Function-) even has the example similar to your case.

Comment: That's perfect, @akarnokd. Thank you. I've posted the answer (for my case) below.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to [@akarnokd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61158/akarnokd) for pointing to the retryWhen [Javadoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#retryWhen-io.reactivex.functions.Function-). Based on that, here's the solution I'm using:

```
public <T> SingleTransformer<T, T> applySchIoAndRetry() {

    return new SingleTransformer<T, T>() {
        @Override
        public SingleSource<T> apply(Single<T> upstream) {
            return upstream
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .retryWhen(errors -> {
                        AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
                        return errors
                                .takeWhile(throwable -> {

                                    if (counter.getAndIncrement() != 3) {

                                        if (throwable instanceof HttpException) {
                                            HttpException exception = (HttpException) throwable;
                                            return (exception.code() == 400);
                                        }
                                    }

                                    return false;
                                })
                                .flatMap(e -> {
                                    System.out.println("delay retry by " + counter.get() + " second(s)");
                                    return Flowable.timer(counter.get(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                                });
                    });
        }
    };
}
```